# Сжатие изображений при загрузке через ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression

Работаю с flickr API для загрузки изображений. В результате обращения к API получаю ссылку на изображение, которую могу вставить в какое-то место на странице: `https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5578/14948350732_6cacca4da6.jpg`. Но весит картинка зачастую больше, чем хотелось бы. И Google Page Insight ругается, к тому же. Можно ли как-то сжимать картинку в lossless/lossy перед отрисовкой на клиенте при помощи JS?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, такие операции затратные и на клиенте такого не сделать. Такое решается только через backend используя сторонние сервисы по сжатию, например [tinypng](http://tinypng.com) или есть такой сервис, который на лету делает сжатие изображения https://imageoptim.com/api или ресайз изображения https://rsz.io/#ImageResizing